# Change background colour of rmarkdown pdf output

Tags: r, pdf, render, rstudio, r-markdown

I am currently using RStudio 0.98.1091 and I am trying to create a pdf document with the render function from the rmarkdown package.

R script:

```
library("rmarkdown")
render("input.Rmd", "pdf_document")
```

input.Rmd

```
---
title: "Report"
output: pdf_document 
---


<style>
  body {background-color:lightgray}
</style>
<body>
  <h1>This is a heading</h1>
  <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
</body>
```

I would like to set the background color of the whole report, out of desperation I tried a few things like using html; with no results.

The document has graphs plotted with R code chunks, tables, and text.

Again, I would like to set the document background color to something else (currently white).

Thanks,

ZeroStack

I am using OS X 10.10.3 with pandoc and MacTex installed.

Comment: The solution needs to be programmatic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, one solution is to use latex i.e. first create a `.Rnw` file which loads the latex `pagecolor` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pagecolor}

\begin{document}

\pagecolor{yellow}
\section{A very yellow page}
<<plot1, echo=FALSE>>=
hist(rnorm(1000))
@
\clearpage
\subsection{Another yellow page}

<<summary1>>=
summary(mtcars)
@

\end{document}
```

In RStudio this will look like:
[image: rstudio]

You now want to convert this `.Rnw` file to a `.tex` file and then to a `.pdf` file. The easiest way this can be done is simply by pressing the `Compile pdf` button in RStudio (shortcut Shift+Cmd+K). 
If you want to do this programatically you first need to convert the `.Rnw` to a `.tex` file with `knitr::knit("foo.Rnw")`, and then doing in the command line: `pdflatex foo.tex`, which will produce the `.pdf` file.

Result:

[image: yellow]

Comment: I think this would've worked well, but the problem is the pagecolor package is not available for R version 3.1.2

Comment: Pagecolor is a latex package.

Comment: I don't fully understand, I tried running your code and got the following:
LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble.

pandoc: Error producing PDF from TeX source
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 43

Comment: Heres a quick question, how are you rendering the Rnw file into a pdf?

Comment: @ZeroStack I just described the workflow in my answer - see the edit.

Comment: thanks! I managed to do it with knit2pdf("foo.Rnw")  from the knitr package.

Comment: Great, I was just going to mention that!