# When knitting .rmd files to .pdf in RStudio, how do I give a different background colour to the output and echos?

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, rstudio, knitr

I have been able to provide a colour to output chunks by following this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29033677/change-background-colour-of-rmarkdown-pdf-output). How do I make it so that the output chunks are a different colour to the code chunks? Also, how do I provide a background colour for the other output messages?

Alternatively, a plain black border around the output and echo chunks would work. Thank you!

[image]

I have used this in the setup currently:

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE, class.output="shadebox")
```

\definecolor{shadecolor}{RGB}{240, 240, 240}
````

Comment: html output? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41030477/changing-chunk-background-color-in-rmarkdown

Comment: I am not aware of an easy solutions but it should be possible by combing output hooks:  https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/output-hooks.html and a latex solution for changing the background color of 'verbatim': https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163412/how-fancyvrb-background-color-fill-completely-with-fillcolor

Comment: @Friede thank you for the suggestion, although I am mainly after a solution for knitting to pdf.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a full answer for you on the different chunk colors (I'll add it if I can find it) - but I can help you added the background color to all your output, messages, warnings, and errors. Just modify your code like this:

````
```{r setup, include = FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(
  echo          = TRUE,
  # Next 4 are various types of output
  class.output  = "shadebox",
  class.message = "shadebox",
  class.warning = "shadebox",
  class.error   = "shadebox"
)
```
````

If you don't want any of those particular types shaded, just delete the line.

Comment: Hi @Quinton.Quagliano, thank you so much for your help. That worked great in giving a background to all other types of outputs. Would be keen to hear back if you've found out how to differentiate the colours between code chunks and output chunks.

Comment: Hello @cejr9565, after some additional inspection, I suspect that one approach would be to look into how syntax highlighting templates work under pandoc, and to create a custom template, but I don't have a clear answer about how to do that yet. Here is a [link](https://pandoc.org/chunkedhtml-demo/13-syntax-highlighting.html) to get you started on that. I'll continue to look into whether there might be a solid way to produce the effects you are looking for. Another approach would be looking into LaTeX packages that offer background coloring.